# recalculate element height in jQuery after class change

Tags: jquery, height, css

I've got a list of items and according to a criteria it gets a class via jQuery on document.ready that triggers CSS3 columns.

If the list is displayed in columns it would have a smaller height. Is there any way to get the new height in jQuery immediately after the class change?

```
$items.each(function(i){

var theItem = this;

console.log($(theItem).height());

//extended layout

if ( theCriteria ) {
    $(theItem).addClass('extended'); 
    console.log('after', $(theItem).height()); }
}
```

The code above returns the initial height on both calls. I'm guessing I need to trigger something else.

Comment: Couldn't you just check the height in the code that changes the class?

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I'll post the code in a sec

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A lot of times, dom manipulation doesn't occur until a function closure is complete.

A good article on the issue: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/08/when_to_read_ou.html

It might be best to do a `setTimeout` function call instead of the direct log.

instead of:

```
console.log('after', $(theItem).height());
```

try

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log('after', $(theItem).height()); }, 0);
```

Setting the timeout to `0` will make it run as soon as possible, while still after the current function that is running.

Hopefully that's your issue. Good luck.