# Jquery .css not applying height property to a div

Tags: jquery, css, height

I'm developing a site and fairly new to jquery. For some reason, when I use the .css() function on one div, it won't change the height. It works on another div but not this one. Here is a link to the website:

http://dev.djrefine.com/epic/index111.html

To activate the function in question, open any article by clicking a grey box, then click the white "close" box in the top right corner.

and the code in question is on line 506 which is the sixth line in this snippet:

```
        var $wWidth = $(window).width();
        var $wHeight = $(window).height();

        var $newheight = Math.round($wHeight * 0.8 - 200) + 'px';

        $('#container').css('height',$newheight);

        $('#theThing').html($newheight);
        $('#thisThing').html($('#container').css('height'));

        $('#makeMeScrollable').css({'height':$wHeight * 0.8 - 200,'width':$wWidth - 260});
```

the div #makeMeScrollable is correctly adjusting its css, but the #container div is not.

The div #theThing and #thisThing are just showing that the $newheight is the correct number, but the container height is not being set to equal that number, as you can see in the demo page

also I've tried to have $newheight not rounding, not adding 'px' on the end, and every other variation I could think of...

Comment: Tried debugging in Chrome and seems to be working as expected. Which browser are you using?

Comment: have you tried to use `.height()` and `.width()` methods instead `.css()` ? Also, the jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js hasn't loaded here (404 response code)

Comment: I am trying in all 5 major browsers and getting the same result in all of them.. jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js isn't used in any of the current scripts, it was for something else... i'll delete that line

Comment: after you click 'close' look on the left below the search bar. There should be two numbers, the top being the variable, and the second line being the actual value of the #container height. Mine is showing 650 for one and 2936 for the other, though they should be the same, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix..

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#container').css('height',$newheight);
        $('#thisThing').html($('#container').css('height'));
        $container.isotope( 'reloadItems' ).isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });
        $container.isotope( 'reLayout' );
        }, 0);
```

thanks goes to Alex Sexton's answer at this post:

[recalculate element height in jQuery after class change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997887/recalculate-element-height-in-jquery-after-class-change)

It basically delays the stuff in the timeout 0 seconds, but having it there forces them to wait until the rest of the function is finished. I don't know WHY it's necessary, but it worked.

Comment: Spent an hour trying to work it out and this answer fixed my problem! Thanks a lot!